# Magento 2 - Order view restriction

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I would like to let customer to see other orders than theirs in their account. The restriction is made by Magento with this code in module-sales/Controller/AbstractController/View.php :

```
$result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
        return $result;
}
```

I don't understand how can I override this ? I looked into the load function but there is nothing...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't think that is the restriction you are looking for. There isn't a restriction really, Magento just loads the orders that are associated with the current customer id. You'd have to do some heavy lifting to extend it to include orders from other customers. In which case, are you trying to allow a customer to see all orders, or only ones from a specific customer group, or list of approved emails, etc.?

Comment: it is not a restriction where you are pointing. Also, where do you want to allow customer to preview all orders? In his dashboard? Could you be more specific about what you are actually trying to achieve?